# "Hypersurface orthogonal" component of covariant derivative of normal vector

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, covariance

I believe that answer to my question is rather trivial but I can't seem to get my head around it. In the context of the ADM formulation of gravity (or any other differential geometry context, I guess) the covariant derivative of a normal vector to the hypersurface/foliation/slice, in any direction within the hypersurface, gives extrinsic curvature. Its components $K_{ij}$ would be e.g. the covariant derivative of a normal vector in direction $i$ projected to direction $j$ where both basis vectors $i$ and $j$ lie in the hypersurface.

My question is, how come that vector which is the covariant derivative of the normal vector along one of these $i$'s always has orthogonal component equal to zero?

**I.e. how come the covariant derivative of normal vector in direction $i$ projected to the normal vector itself always equals zero?**

It isn't true for any other vector, as a matter of fact, using compatibility of a metric from definition of extrinsic curvature $K_{ij}=\bigl(\operatorname{cov}(n,i)\mid j\bigr)$ we can easily see that $\bigl(n\mid \operatorname{cov}(j,i)\bigr)=K_{ij}$ so that the covariant derivative of any other vector $j$ along $i$ does have a component along normal $n$ and it is exactly the extrinsic curvature.

Consequently, I'd assume that the above property of not having an orthogonal component of the covariant derivative is kind of a defining property of a normal vector. I just wonder where this follows from.

Comment: Derivative of normalized vector field is always orthogonal to that vector field.It is easy to visualize that if dervivative of a vector field has component in the direction of this vector field then its length cannot be constant.